# Validity of the boolean expression grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar

Is this grammar correct for parsing boolean expressions?

```
ident = true | false
bxpr  = ident and bxpr | ident or bxpr | not bxpr | ( bxpr ) | ident
```

This so far parsed most of my test cases [using scala parsers]. I see many grammars using terms and factors to create a grammar

Comment: Try this as a test case: `(true) and true`. PS: `ident` is a strange name for something that can only be `true` or `false`. An identifier is usually an arbitrary name. `true` or `false` would more appropriately be called Boolean literals, constants or atoms.

Comment: The reason most people use different non-terminals is so that `a and b or not a and not b` means `(a and b) or ((not a) and (not b))`.  You might want to look at what your grammar does with that and decide whether it is what (you)/(people you know) would expect.